# Unity won't start. What can I do?

Tags: unity

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I set a wget download running overnight and I wake up to the download complete but a frozen Unity interface. I changed to another tty and, with `top`, saw that the process `ibus-daemon` was using ~130% CPU. I killed it and the interface became unfrozen. I restarted the computer. Now, when I log in to Unity at the greeter, I am presented with the wallpaper and nothing else. What can I try to get Unity working?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was addressed by making some space. The download filled up the hard drive completely. While LXDE would launch, Unity wouldn't. It would be helpful if Unity could throw some message if it can't launch for this reason.